# Как узнать номер строки таблицы при нажатии на ячейку?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Добрый день.
Как узнать номер строки таблицы при нажатии на ячейку, используя jquery или angularjs?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью jquery http://jsfiddle.net/tzjrq1vt/2/